# (HTML5) cannot display Chinese characters when using UTF-8

Tags: html, text, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to display some Chinese characters on my web page using HTML5.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// ...

context.fillText('中文', 0, 0);

context.fill();
```

And I have checked several questions here and added the following in the header.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

I tried in Firefox 14, and it shows `????` on the screen. While I realized that, my browser setting of character encoding is `UTF-8`. When I changed it to 'Big5`, it displays well.

My question is, can the script allow browser to display Chinese (and perhaps all other non-English) characters properly without changing to the specific character encoding? i.e. keeping the setting as `UTF-8` and then nothing deal with the user's browsers furthermore because I want my page to display more than one language.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the HTML5 file encoded using UTF-8 or Big5?

Comment: Make sure *everything* is encoded in UTF-8, especially the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have saved your source code in Big5. You should either

- save your source code as UTF-8, OR
- use unicode escape codes for non-ASCII characters.

If you prefer to use escape codes, your example can be written as:

```
context.fillText('\u4e2d\u6587', 0, 0);
```

Comment: It is also possible to keep it Big5 encoded and properly declare that encoding (a `meta` tag may or may not be sufficient for that, depending on server settings). But Big5 does not cover all languages, and UTF-8 does.