# WordPress responsive menu in chinese language

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using this plugin in my wordpress website.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-responsive-menu/
But when i translate my website in chinese language menu items not showing. Please can you suggets me how i can translate it?

Comment: What encoding does your page have? In Firefox tools > page info > encoding.

Answer (score 0):

in this plugins, the folder "lang" is empty... It does not use languages. So you need change php files and i recommend you do not do this.

But if you really need change, use sublimetext or other soft or command line for use best function : "search in folder".

Answer (score 0):

Use WMPL[Multilingual Plugin].

Just install this plugin in your website and just translate each and every menu which has been used in English.{you can even Sync the menus to the selected language}.

When you choose your language the menu gets changed to Chinese language and nothing get affected.

Comment: Menu changing is not issue issue is this when i use responsive menu item not appearing showing empty.

Answer (score 0):

You will most probably need to either change the page encoding or if use an approach like in this answer.
[(HTML5) cannot display Chinese characters when using UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738217/html5-cannot-display-chinese-characters-when-using-utf-8)